# Iterate through an html structure and find a specific href in an a

Tags: html, testing, cypress, href

does anyone how how to iterate though a structure and look for a specific href using cypress??

Example code:

```
<div class="navigation_outer">
   <div class="navigation">
      <div class="navitem ">
         <div class="glyph">
            <i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="label">Homepage</div>
            <a href="/homepage/" title="Homepage"></a>
         </div>
      <div class="navitem ">
         <div class="glyph">
            <i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="label">Live Events</div>
            <a href="/homepage/events" title="Live Events"></a>
         </div>
      <div class="navitem ">
         <div class="glyph">
            <i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i>
         </div>
         <div class="label">Filler</div>
         <a href="/homepage/filler" title="Filler"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Say I wanted to find `href="/homepage/events"` by iterating though that html structure, and click on it for it to take me to that link.

Is there a way of doing this? Because I've been trying to use find(), each(), should(), contain(), invoke(), but nothing seems to work for me

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT!

`cy.contains('div', 'Live Events').next().click()` worked for me so thank you very much for the replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go directly to it, specify the `href` as part of the selector

```js
cy.get('.navitem a[href="/homepage/events"]').click()
```

In the above selector, `a[href="/homepage/events"]` is used to specify the `<a>` element that has `href="/homepage/events"` as an attribute. It gets the single element you need because `href="/homepage/events"` is unique.

You could also use the `title="Live Events"` attribute because it is also unique to your target element.

```js
cy.get('.navitem a[title="Live Events"]').click()
```

---

One more option is to search by label

```js
cy.contains('div', 'Live Events')
  .next()                          // next element is <a>
  .click()
```

Comment: Does `.next()` work with parent/children? I've only used it for siblings before and quickly reading the docs, I would think it only works with siblings.

Comment: `cy.get('.navitem a[href="/homepage/events"]').click()` didn't work for me, I got "cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 3 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element." 

The same happened with `cy.get('.navitem a[title="Live Events"]').click()` "cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 3 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element."

`cy.contains('div', 'Live Events').next().click()` worked for me so thank you very much

Comment: Ok, the reason for that is there are redundant versions of the navigation elements, possibly used for mobile, desktop layouts. It's likely you can add something else before `.navitem` to fix that, but would have to see the whole page to know what to do.

Comment: No `cy.get('div.sp-cf sp-palette-row sp-palette-row-1 span[title="#4a86e8"]').click();` doesn't work either for example, just a div with muntiple spans in it, same sort of structure, doesn't find it "`Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: div.sp-cf sp-palette-row sp-palette-row-1 span[title="#4a86e8"], but never found it`"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each` to iterate through the elements and then click on `href="/homepage/events"`

```js
cy.get('a').each(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.attr('href') == '/homepage/events') {
    cy.wrap($ele).click()
  }
})
```